# Datagridview How to skip blank rows deleted?

Tags: c#

datagridview How to skip blank rows deleted?
this is the following error :

> Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row

this is my code: http://pasted.co/bcb3fb31

Comment: Show your work first.

Comment: this is my code:
http://pasted.co/bcb3fb31
this not work:
`foreach (DataRow row in saleStockWithProviderDataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                    {`

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement SQL `DataTable` event handler like the one shown below:

```
YourDataTable.RowDeleted += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dataTable_RowChanged);

    private void dataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow _dr = e.Row as DataRow;
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
              // YOUR CODE
            }
            if (e.Row.RowState == DataRowState.Added) { //OPTIONAL }
            if (e.Row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified) { //OPTIONAL}
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        finally { _dr = null; }
    }
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: at this code: 
`saleStockWithProviderDataGridView.RowDeleted += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(saleStockWithProviderDataGridView_RowChanged);`

Comment: Please add some clarity regarding the Database and development environment you are using, and check if you properly referenced the corresponding .NET Libraries. Regards,